# Error al mostrar un grafico de torta en Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

Hola estoy haciendo un tablero con shinydashboard, y me salta un error particular cuando quiero mostrar un grafico de torta: attempt to apply non-function
El error no esta en el dataframe, ya que puse un View para que me lo muestre y esta todo correcto (y efectivamente es una variable reactiva), lo curioso es que si yo comento la linea de coord_polar, me muestra perfecto el grafico de barra unica con sus particiones
Tengo entendido que este error se da cuando haces mal uso de una funcion pero no lo encuentro. Para mas info, comento que el df tiene la columna SEXO_L y porcentaje

```
output$ptlo_torta_genero <- renderPlotly({
    plot_pie <- ggplot(agrupado_genero(), aes(x = 2, y = porcentaje, fill = SEXO_L)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white") +
      geom_text(aes(label =percent(porcentaje/100)),
                position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), color = "white", size = 6) +
      coord_polar(theta = 'y') + #aca me salta el error, no entiendo porque
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("salmon", "steelblue",'green')) +
      theme_void() +
      labs(title = "Gráfico de Dona") +
      xlim(0.5, 2.5)
      
    ggplotly(plot_pie, tooltip = "text")
  })
```